# Wildfly 24, deploy application that do not use wildfly security

Tags: security, ejb, wildfly

I have a java application in form of ear that wrapps an ejb, which defines context-root in a submodule. the application does not use any build in wildfly security.

But when I try to access context-root for the application, always get 403 access denied, how to turn off default security.

Comment: Are the EJB's in a WAR? Or do you have a WAR file in your EAR?

Comment: I have an old javaee application, which is a ear have ejd in side, but ear also have a webmodule in form of war which contains rest api, I set the context-root point to war. but when try to access from jboss, it just say 403.
I have another similar old javaee application which is a ear but dont have any ejb inside and point webmodule to war, which works fine. they have same setup except the ejb. so I guess its ejb that caused the problem

Comment: Also that the application do not use any wildfly security in ejb or war. I tried setup security realm and set missing-method-permissions-deny-access to false, but still not working

Comment: Are you making a remote EJB call? Or what call is getting the 403?

Comment: I have an old application from wildfly 11 wich i migrate to wildfly 24. its an ear with a webmodule war and an ejb inside. in the war there are several stateless bean for rest api. it does not use any wildfly build in security. there is also a swagger wwar which does test call to rest api. I tried both swagger and used postman try to access the api. it returns 404 and the error page i defined in the web.xml always get returned. but if i try to access context-root from wildfly admin it returns 403.

Comment: now i am supecting the rest endpoints are not setup correctly, but there is no error in the log, and all enpoints seem deployed correctly

Comment: It's tough to say what it could be really. If it's Jakarta EE compliant it should definitely work.